# What is the rationale behind forcing a 24 hour wait period to award a bounty after issuing one?

Tags: discussion, bounty

In the scenario where a question has been asked and answered and you wish to award an additional bounty for the existing answer, forcing a 24 hour wait to award the bounty seems a bit... strange to me.  Especially, if the question was dead for a few days.

Does anyone know what the rationale behind forcing a 24 hour wait period to award a bounty after issuing one is?

Comment: Furthermore, I am wondering: What's the rationale behind having to wait until one can add a bounty to a question?

Comment: I think this particular case should forgo the 24 hr requirement. There just are some cases when an answer is so worthy that it merits the recognition this would bring.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, the purpose of bounties is to attract attention to a question, not to award reputation.  That purpose is still served by choosing the "one of these answers is exemplary" option, even if all you want to do is award additional unicorn points to an answer.

Users who roam the halls of "featured" questions still have the option to provide a stellar answer that's even better than the one you want to award, although I suppose that motivation might diminish if they see the "exemplary" banner.

In other words, if the modus operandi for placing a bounty is to get attention for a question, rather than the secondary effect of awarding additional rep (even if you choose the "exemplary" option), then the reasons for having a 24 hour delay are still valid.

Comment: Hey Robert .. "In general, the purpose of bounties is to attract attention to a question, not to award reputation."  That's an odd one - are you saying that's your opinion, or, generally accepted by the community, or, is it official policy of the SO business, or?  Cheers...

Comment: Whilst I think the minimum twenty-four hour wait is helpful in the *majority* of cases, where the explicit "Reward existing answer" reason is chosen I do think it is a bit inconsistent to then enforce a wait in case of future outstanding answers - albeit I accept an existing answer, however impressive, may not be the canonical answer for the question (unless written by Jon Skeet of course). Maybe it should be reworded to "Reward outstanding answer"? This infers there is an existing answer in mind, but sets expectations for the bounty awarder as well.

Comment: All I really wanted was to award additional unicorn points to an answer. I wish this were possible.

Comment: Actually, I just came across a very old answer to a very old question.  One answer was accepted but the other I found outstandingly good.  Maybe due to its esoteric topic it had drawn little attention, though, and I just wanted to award the outstanding answer, not draw any attention to that question when I opened my bounty.  Now I might draw attention, right, but what's the rational behind this?  There is an accepted answer and one I found outstanding.  Why should I redirect the attention of members away from other more recent questions?  I don't see the point in this case.

Comment: "In general, the purpose of bounties is to attract attention to a question, not to award reputation."  - *inserts why not both meme*. But seriously, sometimes we want to *avoid* cluttering the bounties section with questions that *aren't* true bounties (if the bounty is already pre-determined, then it's not the same as the others). From my view, the delay causes numerous problems, yet adds no value.

Comment: For future reference, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61357019/change-x-axis-labels-to-hours-time-on-geom-tile#comment109097060_61357163) is a brief explanation of the nuisance the delay caused myself, and the unnecessary effort it caused others to go to since they saw it in the bounty section and didn't realise it was for an existing answer. Bad UX in my view. I really hope it is changed, as bounties are a great way of improving the quality of answers, and they should be encouraged, not made unnecessarily administratively burdensome.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to venture a guess it is to enforce the democratic nature of the site. If every question could have a bounty added, than only the "richest" users would get their questions noticed or asked, in return increasing their own riches further (good question, etc). A plethora of bounty questions would then bury non-bounty questions and it would become a highly negative feedback loop. The waiting period allows questions to be posted on equal footing while providing for a a sort of aftermarket for users with reputation to spare and users who want to earn the same. Seems fair to me.

Comment: I think you're thinking of the wrong waiting period. This feels like an answer to _"Why do we have to wait two days to post a bounty?"_ rather than answering _"Why, after we have posted a bounty, must we wait a day to select the answer to reward?"_