# Why can't a bounty created to reward an existing answer be awarded immediately?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I asked a question a while back which received a really great answer. It's now a few weeks later and I just started a bounty and chose the reason as wanting to reward an existing answer, but when I try to award it a message says I can't award it for another 23 hours.

Doesn't it seem like I should be able to award the bounty immediately since it's for an existing answer?

Comment: Whats the hurry?  An answer lingering on the **Featured** tab collects upvotes over time as well.  I rather like it when my answer lingers on the **Featured** tab for several days.  It can collect more points from UpVotes than it will get from a small bounty.

Comment: One of the reasons is it shines a bring light on any *abuse* too, like trying to transfer reputation to a sock-puppet account. Being able to insta-award the bounty would vastly reduce community scrutiny.

Comment: At a minimum, it is an unpleasant surprise to the bounty-giver.

Comment: I agree with OP. If the reason is "reward existing answer" then it's stupid to have to wait 23 hours since *you already know what answer you created the bounty for*.

Comment: I suggest this be re-opened, as this is *not* a duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254103 . That question is about bounties *in general*. This question is about bounties which are *specifically* created to reward an answer which already exists. When it comes to the matter of whether or not there should be an enforced delay before the bounty can be awarded, the two subjects are notable different.

Comment: Yeah this is not a duplicate. I voted to reopen it but I've literally never seen a single question be reopened on StackOverflow because the people that love moderating love exercising their power to close questions, not being reasonable and reopening them, so I won't hold my breath.

Comment: @Timmmm The case is not so bad, sometimes they get reopen, but the general suppressive behavior of the community (and, particularly the MSO community), I think, undeniable. If you have some sql affinity, you could play a lot with the SEDE ( https://data.stackexchange.com ). I think a slow change into a better direction is possible, *but it requires you to constantly represent your views, despite the downwind*. If we are silent, nothing will be ever better.

Comment: @phils If your English is better than mine, I think you could make the difference more clear by applying a non-essential change to the post.

Comment: @phils (Btw, I think the difference between the question is not enough significant to make a clear leave open/reopen decision, thus a voting to close as dupe was not so bad idea.)

Comment: If it isn't clear to you whether or not a question is a duplicate, *don't close it*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My opinion on this is that perhaps it could be awarded immediately, but what would that gain? Save you a little bit of time perhaps in having to deal with having a bounty?

On the other hand, letting the bounty sit for rewarding an existing answer basically doubles the effect, as everyone who visits the question sees that exemplary answer and gives it more upvotes.

Letting the bounty sit increases exposure to that answer, so the best thing you can do really is to set the bounty up, perhaps indicate which answer you found bounty worthy in the comment, and let it sit until it expires and then award it to allow for maximum exposure to this content. The answerer will appreciate it.

Comment: As will all other posters there. Which might even make the bounty pay for itself ;-)

Comment: Hi Travis .... fair enough.

Comment: What do you gain? Not forgetting to reward the bounty! If you created the bounty for the specific purpose of rewarding an existing answer, then that means you *already know what answer you want to reward*. Having to wait 23 hours drastically increases the chances I forget about it and never give the bounty. It makes no sense to wait in the case where you already are trying to reward an *existing* answer, not one that will come in 23 hours.

Comment: Yeah, a minor inconvenience though, considering you are *rewarding* the answer, and every minute of exposure it gets through the post being bountied also has a large amount of value. The point is to give back to the post, in your scenario, is it not?

Comment: This issue makes no sense to me.  "Reward existing answer" shouldn't be a reason to select from if you're not allowed to...reward the existing answer. Otherwise rename it to "reward best answer" or something not infuriating.

Comment: @Tommy - Please create a feature request with regards to your position then, and the community can weigh in.

Comment: My feature request is the same as what the OP posted here.

Comment: So instantly? Yeah, that would introduce a lot of abuse opportunity, fails to give enough attention in general, and would make the bounty system less of a highlighted section while making it more of a straight reputation transfer and nothing else. Why don't you look around the site at some existing FR for the bounty system if you are so adamant. If you are not willing to put in any effort aside from these low quality comments, perhaps you should move on to another topic.

Comment: Who says that an immediately awarded answer can't stay on the bounty list? There could simply be an "automatically reward this answer in 24 hours"-button.

Comment: After learning that there is an arbitrary 24 hour delay between creating a bounty for an existing answer and being able to actually award it, I feel it is disrespectful of others' time since they'll click on it from the 'Bountied' section (wasting their time), and possibly even start trying to answer it if they don't notice the reason for the bounty. A counter-question - does the 24 hour delay achieve anything? (I'm open minded - is it, like, anti rep-laundering or something?).

Comment: So we aren't talking so much about the time of the bounty initiator (although their time is important too), but more the time of every single user who clicks on it pointlessly.

Comment: Also, commenting to the answer something like 'thanks, there's a bounty coming your way" is meaningless clutter to people using the site for info.

Comment: For future reference, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61357019/change-x-axis-labels-to-hours-time-on-geom-tile#comment109097060_61357163) is an outline of the time wasting it caused myself and another user (Eric's time was wasted answering a question that already had a great answer, and I felt guilty not awarding a *second* bounty). IMO bounties are a great way of encouraging high quality answers and should **not** be made unnecessarily administratively burdensome. I will think twice before I give one again, and that's *not* a desirable ethos for the site AFAIK.

Comment: PS @TravisJ I don't direct my comments toward you, I just put them here so you + others can be aware of the effect of the delay, and its unintended consequences

Answer (score -2):

The situation might be different for new/own questions vs. old ones. New ones profit from the added bonus TravisJ mentioned, and if it is your own question, the bounty might be free.

On the other hand, if the question is several years old and not your own, there might be no new answers possible, except low-quality ones that hope to get the bounty. So it lingers on on the *Featured questions* tab, where it is not easy to see if a new answer is needed or not. It just seems unnecessary to keep the waiting period when even the text of the bounty states that it is for existing answers.

A simple choice would solve the problem: reduce the minimum time for this specific type to zero, but leave everything else as is. Therefore, everybody can either award it instantly (reducing visual clutters for others) or let it stay (increasing possible upvotes on the question and other answers.

Comment: I wish I could reward this answer with a bounty.