# Why is there a time delay in using a bonus to reward an existing option?

Tags: discussion

I'm still trying to understand the rationale of introducing a time delay in using a bounty to reward an existing answer.

This question was asked already and received one answer which the answerer himself described as an 'opinion', but I didn't understand it . . .

[Why can't a bounty created to reward an existing answer be awarded immediately?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288643/why-cant-a-bounty-created-to-reward-an-existing-answer-be-awarded-immediately)

in the specific case where I'm doing this there are many answers and the one I'm rewarding is **not** the accepted answer.   So the premise of the above answer, that it will draw attention to a good answer, may not draw attention to one I'm rewarding.

In any case, if someone wanted to leave a bounty open for a while to draw attention to a good answer, they could decide on their own to delay applying their bounty.  So what's the reason for an **enforced** delay?   This forces me to save a link to the question, and save some notes about what I intended to do, and which answer it was, and put an alert in my calendar to pop up a alarm to remind me go back and check it before the bounty time expires, and log back in, etc.   A lot of overhead just to give someone some rep points.

My goal is just to reward an answer that saved me a lot of trouble, nothing else.

Comment: [As Martijn commented](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288643/why-cant-a-bounty-created-to-reward-an-existing-answer-be-awarded-immediately#comment168729_288643), one of the reasons for the delay is to prevent immediate rep transfers to sock puppet accounts.

Comment: What's a sock puppet account?   I assume it's something nefarious but is it common, or is this like making complicated voter-registration laws to prevent vote-fraud in countries where vote fraud seldom happens anyway, i.e., inconveniencing the vast majority of good-guys to defeat a vanishingly-small portion of bad guys?